# Large File Upload Using Lighttpd and CGI

Tags: upload, cgi, lighttpd

I am trying to upload large file using lighttpd and then serve it through CGI C routine.

When i upload files less than 64KB things are alright, but when i try to upload large file, lighttpd err log shows the following and exits with *HTTP 500 Internal Server Error*.

> /mod_cgi.c.1135) write() failed due to:  Broken pipe

I have developed a web page, which will post data with multipart/form-data.

Waiting for the response.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: That would suggest the issue is with your CGI. Are you using a CGI library with tweakable parameters regarding max file size or timeout?

Comment: My CGI is just a c routine, which take environment variable etc. Not using cgi library. I have solved the problem by making lighttpd write into file if the file size is greater than 64KB. And then my cgi opens the file and processes its accordingly.  For curiosity Martin Can you please eloborate more.